# jqModal dialog always under overlay

Tags: jquery, jqmodal

I have the following code, and am at my wit's end because the dialog always appears under the overlay.  Any advice will be most appreciated:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="../Styles/jqModal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">
        #shift-edit-popup
        {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jqModal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#shift-edit-popup").jqm({
                toTop: true
            }).jqmAddTrigger("#show-button");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form" runat="server">
    <input id="show-button" type="button" value="Show" />
    <div id="shift-edit-popup">
        <div>
            <asp:Label ID="resourceLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="resourceList">Resource:</asp:Label>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="resourceList" runat="server" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ResourceId" Width="120px">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I saw and tried you need to use the included jqmWindow class on your dialog div and drop the this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #shift-edit-popup
    {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

Your code should look something like this:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="Scripts/jqModal.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jqModal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#shift-edit-popup").jqm({
                toTop: true,
                modal: true
            }).jqmAddTrigger("#show-button");
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form" runat="server">
    <input id="show-button" type="button" value="Show" />
    <div id="shift-edit-popup" class="jqmWindow">
        <div>
            Resource:
            <select><option value="1">One</option><option value="2">Two</option></select>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

(You just need to change the script and css references accordinly)

Comment: Thank you!  This was just the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to set position of the shift-edit-popup:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #shift-edit-popup
    {
       display: none;
       position : relative;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Which version of jqModal.js do you use?

The last official version from http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/ is not compatible with jQuery 1.4.x (see http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jqdnr-dragging-problem-with-jquery-1-4 and http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/jqgrid-jquery-1-4/).

If in your version "$()" exist inside of jqModal.js, it should be replaced with "$(document)". You can also download fixed version as a part of jqGrid package: http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6.

Comment: Ah, yes, I have the latest version, and jQuery 1.4.2.  Thanks, I'll follow up your links tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Check the z-index values of the overlay and the modal box.

Comment: I've tried z-index values both lesser and greater than the overlay to no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will be helpful reading: [Understanding z-index](http://tjkdesign.com/articles/everything_you_always_wanted_to_know_about_z-index_but_were_afraid_to_ask.asp)

Comment: Thanks, but jqModal is supposed to take care of the z-index on its target elements.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a problem like this not to long ago. Try changing the DOCTYPE to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```